# Using ampersand (&) inside gsub R function for pattern replacement (backreference to capture group)

Tags: r, regex, backreference, capture-group

I need to add a prefix to some elements in the vector which match a special pattern.

Inside `sed` `Unix` command ampersand has a special meaning (backreference to a capture group) and I'm trying to get similar functionality in `gsub` `R` function.

```
# create a small example
v1=c(1:10,"D")
# perform the command to add a prefix to vector elements
gsub("^[0-9]+","X.\\&",v1)
```

Output I got:

```
[1] "X.&" "X.&" "X.&" "X.&" "X.&" "X.&" "X.&" "X.&" "X.&" "X.&" "D"
```

Output I want:

```
[1] "X.1" "X.2" "X.3" "X.4" "X.5" "X.6" "X.7" "X.8" "X.9" "X.10" "D"
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears like you're looking for the concept of a **capture group** and **backreference**.

Quoting the BSD sed manual

> An ampersand ('&') appearing in the replacement is replaced by the
>   string matching the RE.  The special meaning of '&' in this context
>   can be suppressed by preceding it by a backslash.  The string '\#',
>   where '#' is a digit, is replaced by the text matched by the
>   corresponding backreference expression

R doesn't support the `&` version, but does support `\#`.
From `?regex`

> The backreference \N, where N = 1 ... 9, matches the substring
>   previously matched by the Nth parenthesized subexpression of the
>   regular expression

So you could do

```
gsub("^([0-9]+)","X.\\1", v1)
#  [1] "X.1"  "X.2"  "X.3"  "X.4"  "X.5"  "X.6"  "X.7"  "X.8"  "X.9"  "X.10" "D"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use backreferences in R regular expressions, as well. You only have to group your pattern by using brackets:

```
gsub("(^[0-9]+)","X.\\1",v1)
```